# Active or Passive strategy?

Tags: portfolio-management

From my reading, passive portfoliomanagement means to replicate an index, active portfoliomanagement means to deviate from an index.

Does that mean that e.g. rules-based investing is actually an active investment approach?

I wrote on an exam, that passive means to follow a certain rule, while active trading means to dynamically decide individually by a portfolio manager.

Comment: Maybe you could invent another label like "quantitative investment strategies" or "rules based investing" as a subset of active management. It sounds like the material is challenging you to think about nomenclature and taxonomy within a field and whether it maps what you see as reality. I don't want to interfere with that process by giving the answer I'm pretty sure a finance exam grader expects. You're probably better off taking courses in the philosophy department anyway. But I think you're on track for aligning with the SEC's definitions as regards ETFs, so that's useful.

Comment: @NathanS. "I don't want to interfere with that process by giving the answer I'm pretty sure a finance exam grader expects." What answer do you mean?

Comment: Some investment companies have mutual fund offerings called Enhanced Index funds.  These are mutual funds that quantitatively track a stock market index, but with modifications such as position sizes, the exclusion of certain securities, or, particularly,  the use of leverage.  They are "rules-based" and so frequently fall into the category of index funds but have higher fees and quite different performance from conventional index funds.